# Mysql `AND` operator

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql

Good day!
i've got some problem with that query:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `test`
WHERE `name`
LIKE "somename" AND `id` = (SELECT max(`id`) FROM test)
```

It returned an empty result.

But

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `test`
WHERE `name` LIKE "somename"
```

works.

Moreover,

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `test`
WHERE `id` = (SELECT max(`id`) FROM test)
```

works too.

Why they doesn't work together?

Thanks you!

Comment: It does not work because `someone` does not have also the highest `id` in the table.

Comment: you are note getting any result in the first query just because both conditions are working together

Comment: Not noted in the answers is the fact that your queries should not "work" at all.  You have used single quotes for the column names, so they are interpreted as string literals.  *Only* use single quotes for  string and date constants, never for column or table names.

Comment: Yeah. Now i understand it. thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  test
WHERE
  id=(SELECT max(id) FROM test WHERE name LIKE "somename")
```

this will return the row from test that has the maximum ID where name is like "somename"

Answer (score 2):

Because they would have to be both true at the same time.

Imagine the following

```
id    name
1     'somename'
2     'someothername'
```

In the above case

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `test`
WHERE `name` LIKE "somename"
```

Will return the first row but:

```
SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM test)
```

Will return the second. Using `AND` will mean no results are returned. You may wish to use `OR` depending on what behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
  SELECT `id`
  FROM `test`
  WHERE id in (SELECT max(id) FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%somename%')
```